# Game theory,core and nucleolus

Tags: game-theory

Let $(N; v)$ be the a TU-game where $N = \{1,2,....,n\}; v(\emptyset) = 0 $ and

$$v(S)=\begin{cases}
S-1&S\text{ odd}\\
S+1&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

1.Calculate for which $n$ the core of the game is nonempty

2.Find the nucleolus for all $n$

1)I triend and:  if $n$ is odd

$\sum_{i\in N/\{i\} }x_i \geq n   $ that is in contrast with $\sum_{i\in N }x_i =n-1  $ but i don't understand how apply this in the case of $n$ even .

2)The solution of my teacher is that the nucleolus is the same of the shapley value (that it's easy to find) but i can't understand why.

Comment: I don't think terms like "TU-game" and "nucleolus" are well known.  You need to give us some references.

Comment: TU game :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transferable_utility Nucleolus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_game_theory#The_nucleolus

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your game is defined by $v(\emptyset)=0$, and

\begin{equation*}
v(S) = \begin{cases}
       |S|-1,  & \text{if}\; |S| \;\text{odd}\;  \\
       |S|+1,  & \text{otherwise}\;
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Then the game is symmetric, and it is well known that for symmetric games the Shapley value and the nucleolus coincide, which is given by $x_{i}=v(N)/n$ for all $i \in N$. Moreover, if the game is symmetric, then the center $\vec{x}$ must be an element of the core, if it exists. Thus, we have to establish for core existence that $x(S)=|S|\,v(N)/n \ge v(S)$ must hold for all $S \subseteq N$. However, this is not anymore satisfied for $n \ge 3$.